# Python: [...] at End of List

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I've run into an issue when after I append my list to my dictionary, I get an unwanted `[...]` at the end of my list.

Here's my code:

```
class Account:

    accountInfo = {} #ex. ID : 5FE19C (hexadecimal ID's)

    def __init__(self):
        choice = raw_input("Would you like to login or signup?\n")
        if choice.lower() == "login":
            self.login()

        elif choice.lower() == "signup":
            print "Great! Fill in the following."
            self.signup()

        else:
            self.__init__()

    def signup(self):

        accountID = '%010x' % random.randrange(16**10) # 10 digit hexadecimal ID generator
        personalInfo = []

        self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo

        firstName = raw_input("First Name: ")
        lastName = raw_input("Last Name: ")
        email = raw_input("E-Mail: ")
        password = raw_input("Password: ")
        birthdate = raw_input("DOB (DD/MM/YYYY): ")
        alias = raw_input("Username/Alias: ")

        personalInfo.append(firstName)
        personalInfo.append(lastName)
        personalInfo.append(email)
        personalInfo.append(password)
        personalInfo.append(birthdate)
        personalInfo.append(alias)

        self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)

        print self.accountInfo
```

And here is my output:

```
>>> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'birthdate', 'alias', [...]]}
```

Just wondering why it appears and how to remove it.

Thanks!

Comment: The Ellipses indicates a recursively defined structure. In your cases you have appended the list to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand what exactly happened, you need to know about references.

```
>>> a = []
>>> test['a'] = a
>>> a.append(1)
>>> a.append(2)
>>> test['a'] 
[1, 2]
```

When you did the line `self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`
What it actually did was pass the reference of `personalInfo` to `self.accountInfo[accountID]`

Meaning modifying `personalInfo` will also reflect in `self.accountInfo[accountID]`

```
self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo >> {'a92ab2fcea': []}

personalInfo.append(firstName) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName']} # Note: Since personalInfo changed, so self.accountInfo[accountID] also changed.

personalInfo.append(lastName) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName','lastName']}

personalInfo.append(email) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName','lastName','email']}

personalInfo.append(password) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName','lastName','email','password']}

personalInfo.append(birthdate) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName','lastName','email','password','birthdate']}

personalInfo.append(alias) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName','lastName','email','password','birthdate','alias']}

self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo) >> {'a92ab2fcea': ['firstName', 'lastName', 'email', 'password', 'birthdate', 'alias', [...]]} # What you are doing is appending personalInfo to personalInfo
```

What I think you meant to do is:

1. remove `self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`
2. replace `self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo) with self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`

But if you understand the reference concept,

1. keep `self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo`
2. remove `self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)`
   Should also work!

But the latter way is discouraged as it is less readable.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Also, wouldn't either of the instructions you provided do the same thing? I don't mean as far as output because they obviously give the same output, but just overall writing that code would give you the same written reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean

```
self.accountInfo[accountID].append(personalInfo)
```

to be

```
self.accountInfo[accountID] = personalInfo
```

you also don't need the latter line earlier in the code.